# NUnit equivalent for JUnit test state management with @Before/@After

Tags: junit, nunit, nunit-3.0

I come from Java world and I mostly used JUnit, and now I have some problems expressing some aspects of tests with NUnit 3. In JUnit, each test creates its own instance of a test class, so it's perfectly valid to create some instance variables in a test class, set up them in `@Before` method, test method and helpers can access these variables freely without worrying they would be overwritten by other tests run in parallel, and `@After` tears down the test data nicely. With NUnit it does not work and `SetUp` and `TearDown` methods seem to be useless in this case, because test fixture instance is reused between invocations of test method(s), so fields of test fixture class can (and are) overwritten by every invocation of a test method (my class has a few test methods, and each of them generates several test cases, so there are some tens of invocations in one test run).

I do not know how to work around this problem. In my scenario, set up would create a temporary folder, which would be used as a work folder for following test case. Tear down would delete the temporary folder afterwards, cleaning up all intermediate files created by tested method. But now, when `SetUp` creates and stores a temporary folder path in instance field (so it can be read by test logic and somewhat complicated asserts and verifiers), the value of such field is overwritten by test cases run in parallel. I considered several approaches:

- implement an `IDisposable` which would represent a context of each test, and enclose it with `using` in each test method - I do not like this idea, because I do not like the idea of `IDisposable` being used as anything else than resource management tool and combinig `IDisposable` with `using` to simulate set up/tear down smells to me like an abuse of this particular language feature,
- create a method which accepts a delegate for actual test logic, and which invokes custom `SetUpTestCase`/`TearDownTestCase` methods. The method would invoke set up, then test delegate, and tear down afterwards. What I do not like about this approach is that it does not play well with test methods which accept parameters - each set of test methods parametrized in particular way would need a corresponding delegate type. Also it somewhat seems to be against spirit of NUnit and the way of describing test methods with attributes - after all, why should the main logic of my test be delegated to anything? Shouldn't the `[Test]` or `[TestCase]` method be actual test?
- maybe there's some way to use more advanced aspects of NUnit, like actions or some callbacks/triggers/whatever, I am just too unexperienced to see these. What I particularly miss is the way to transfer data from set up method (for example, a path to a temporary folder created by it) to the test method that follows. I cannot use instance fields for this, and I do not know whether there exists any "tag" structure which would pass test-specific data between methods invoked on different stages of a test lifecycle?

Generally, `SetUp` and `TearDown` attributes seem pretty useless to me, if they cannot set up the test case without their result being overwritten immediately by another test case run in parallel. What am I missing here?

How can I implemented such per-test case, scoped setup/tear down behavior with NUnit? What do I do wrong, or what do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

As you have established, the TestFixture class is instantiated once before the `OneTimeSetUp` is called; then for each test it runs a set of `SetUp`, `Test` and `TearDown`; and finally, the `OneTimeTearDown`.

If you want the tests to be run in parallel (which is not the default) then you must specify The [Parallelizable Attribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute). Whether you do that or not, it is a good idea for your tests to be written independently, so they do not conflict with each other - they need to be structured.

The AAA (Arrange, Act, Assert) pattern is a common way of structuring unit tests for a method under test. If your tests are to be run in parallel, then TestFixture fields are not suitable for holding information which may conflict across parallel tests, in the same way that it wouldn't be suitable in a multithreaded class.

I'd suggest using a private method in the TestFixture to set up the temporary folder - it will need to have some way of providing a unique folder name, so that the parallel tests do not interact - perhaps use a Guid or CallerMemberName as part of the folder name, and return the folder name.

This method should be called from the Arrange part of the test. And you'll need a try...finally wrapping the rest of the Test to ensure the folder gets torn down. Or you could go with your IDisposable idea - I don't think there's anything wrong with that: the whole point of that is to guarantee tidying up resources (both managed and unmanaged) when something goes out of scope.

Your second suggestion of a delegate would also be fine if you used lambda expressions rather than strictly-defined delegates - the lambda expression can capture variables from the containing scope.